# Selecting points of intersection given a point and equations of lines

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

[image]

I have an $x$-axis and a $y$-axis both beginning from the origin. I also have $n$ straight lines with known equation ($n$=4 in the diagram). If all intercepts of the lines to the axes are positive, then at most I have ${n \choose 2} + 2n$ points of intersection.

The question is, of these points of intersection, how do I determine the ones that form the boundary of the region that contains a point $M$ with known coordinates? In the diagram they are coloured red. I am interested in knowing how these points can be selected from all points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every intersection point $L_i \cap L_j$ and every *other* line $L_k$, check if $L_k$ separates $L_i \cap L_j$ from $M$. If no line separates $L_i \cap L_j$ from $M$, then $L_i \cap L_j$ is one of the adjacent points.

The check for separation is done by the sign test outlined in the other answer. If $L_k$ has the equation $ax+by-c = 0$, we can check the signs of $ax+by-c$ at $M$ and at $L_i \cap L_j$. The line $L_k$ separates the two points if we get different signs.

---

In terms of efficiency: this takes $\Theta(n^3)$ operations, which might be the best we can do if we only need to check this for one point $M$.

If we're going to be doing this check for lots of points, we can probably get this down to an $\Theta(\log n)$ search. "Probably" because I'm not sure which guarantees we can make about balance; but definitely we can promise $O(n)$. There's only a few different possible answers: one for each region. On average, a single sign test distinguishes between about half the regions. You just need to build a binary tree that plans out which signs to check in which order.

Start with all $\binom n2 + 2n$ intersection points. Pick a line $L_i$ such that the two groups "points with a nonnegative sign test" and "points with a nonpositive sign test" are as equal in size as possible. Then repeat with each group, recursively. At a level where no lines distinguish the remaining points, we know that we have the corners of a region, and that's a leaf of our tree.

Answer (score 0):

Two hints to help solve this problem

1. The lines divide the plane into mutually non-intersecting regions, and the point $M$ must lie in exactly one of these regions
2. Each of these regions has a unique representation through the vertices of that region

Hence, if we can find the region, and figure out how to map the region to it's vertices, we can essentially find the vertices you need for any point $M$

Further, if you substitute he point $M$ into the equation of each line, you will get a set of values - some positive and some negative. Each region is uniquely determined by the signs of these numbers

Comment: The thing is, if I substitute $M$ into $L_3$ it gives a positive value, like all other lines in the diagram, but as shown $L_3$ is nowhere involved in forming the boundary.